# Why does my PyQt new window open minimised? (And how to prevent that?)

Tags: python, pyqt

So, basically I have a main window, with a bunch of buttons, which open different windows. On startup, I would like to open up all of them. The problem I am facing is, they are opening up minimised for some reason.  I cannot figure out why?

```
class mainwinActions(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        ...
        self.open_all_win()

    def open_all_win(self):
        self.open_exp()
        self.open_lick()
        self.open_door()

    def open_exp(self):
        self.expwin = fooWin()
        self.expwin.show()
    # The same for self.open_lick/self.open_door
```

Also, I have a button attached to the function.

```
self.openAllButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.open_all_win())
```

And the button does NOT have the same problem. It opens up the windows normally (non-minimised/windowed).

What I tried:

```
class fooWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_fooWin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        ...
        if self.windowState() == QtCore.Qt.WindowState.WindowMinimized:
        # Window is minimised. Restore it.
            self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowState.WindowActive)
```

I also tried replacing self.open_all_win() with

```
self.openAllButton.click()
```

Edit: Reproducible code

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget

import sys


class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Push for Window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        
        self.show_new_window()

    def show_new_window(self):
        self.w = AnotherWindow()
        self.w.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Edit2: Just to clarify, the problem is only on startup. When I run the code, I want all the windows up without clicking on any button. The windows should be visible when I run the file.

**QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR = 6.2.3**

**OS:MacOS Monterey and Windows 10**

Comment: Are you sure that they are actually minimized, and not just *hidden* by (behind) the main window?

Comment: I don't understand, and we can't help if you miss out important aspects. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante no, I did not miss out any important aspects. In fact, I added an unimportant aspect in my comment. My reply should’ve been - no, I can see with my eyes, it’s minimised. And when I click on the button attached to the same function, the windows open up normally

Comment: With the code above I don't reproduce the issue: the new `AnotherWindow` instance window is properly shown. If *with the above code* the new window is actually minimized, please provide the OS type/version and Qt version (`QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR`, not the PyQt version).